# How to throw out a value in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, calculator

I'm creating a diving calculator program. Asks for the level of difficulty. the program then asks for the 7 scores from judges 1-7, stores them in an array, throws out the smallest and largest values then finds the sum of the the remaining. The remaining is then multiplied by the level of difficulty and 0.6. My issue is with my findLargest function, it's as if i'm not calling it all. CODE:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int judgesScore[7]; //array name
float difficulty; //between 1.2 & 3.8
float finalScore; 



void collectInput() {
    int input;

    for (int i=0; i < 7; i++){
        input = -1;
        while (input < 0 || input > 10) {
            cout << "Enter the score of judge " << i+1 << ": ";
            cin >> input;   
        }
         judgesScore[i]=input;
    }
}//end collectInput

int findsmallest () {
    int smallest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        if (judgesScore[i] < judgesScore[smallest]){
            smallest = i;
        }

    }
    return smallest;
}//end smallest


int findlargest () {
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        if (judgesScore[i] < judgesScore[largest]){
            largest = i;
            cout << "the largest is: "<<largest;
        }

    }
    return largest;
}//end largest

int sumOfScore(){
    int smallest = findsmallest();
    int largest = findlargest();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i =0; i <7; i++){
        if( i !=smallest && i !=largest){
            sum+= judgesScore[i];

        }
    }
    return sum;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    while (!(difficulty >= 1.2 && difficulty <= 3.8) ){
        cout << "Please enter the level of difficulty from 1.2 - 3.8: ";
        cin  >> difficulty;


    }//end of while
        collectInput();
        cout << "the sum of scores is "<<sumOfScore() << endl;

        finalScore = (sumOfScore() * difficulty) * 0.6;
        cout 
             << "at a difficulty level of " << difficulty << "\n"
             << "Final Score: " << finalScore << "\n";
```

Comment: *"it's as if i'm not calling it all."* Why do you think so? What are the inputs, expected and actual output?

Comment: Did you mean to use the `<` operator? Also, what if all the scores are the same? Your code would not add any of those scores to the sum.

Comment: except missing final `}`, works [here](https://ideone.com/GFJhms).

Answer (score 0):

Try this! Your printing the index for the largest should be outside the for loop, and some modifications in comparison.

```
int findlargest () {
    int j = 0, largest = judgesScore[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
        if (judgesScore[i] < largest){
            largest = judgesScore[i];
            j = i;
        }
    }
    cout << "the largest is: "<< j;
    return j;
}//end largest
```

Answer (score 0):

your findlargest function is the same with findsmallest function, so the result is smallest == largest.Please careful~ ^_^

```
int findlargest () {
int largest = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++){
    if (judgesScore[i] > judgesScore[largest]){
        largest = i;
        cout << "the largest is: "<<largest;
    }

}
return largest;
```

}//end largest